# Append <hidden> into new <form> element after AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a.html which includes

```
<input type="button" class="add" />
<div id="middle"></div>
```

and inside b.html i have

```
 <form>
   <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

When `.add` button is clicked i am loading `b.html` into `#middle` with Jquery

```
$("#middle").load('b.html');
```

After that i want to add `<input type="hiddden" />` element into `form` as its first child. I use `$('#middle').first().append()`  however it does not work. How can i append it after using AJAX $.load() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to append *something*.  `.append()` by itself won't do anything.  It also sounds like you want to target the `form` element, not just the `div`.

So something like this:

```
$('#middle form').append('<input type="hiddden" />');
```

This, of course, would need to execute after your AJAX call completes:

```
$("#middle").load('b.html', function() {
    $('#middle form').append('<input type="hiddden" />');
});
```

(Note that the use of `.first()` is entirely unnecessary in this case, since `$("#middle")` should only ever return at most one element.)

Comment: if i write it like $("#middle").load('b.html'); $('#middle form').append('<input type="hiddden" />'); It does not work. However your codes works. What is the difference?

Comment: @WebberDepor: The difference is that `.load()` is asynchronous.  Your way would execute the second line of code before the AJAX call completes, so there is no `form` yet at that time.